# How can I reference a Blazor Hybrid project’s form or component in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, blazor-hybrid

I’ve created a Blazor Hybrid project and referenced it in a WinForms project, but the styles are not displaying correctly

this is program.cs
[image]

This is my execution result
[image]
[image]

this my config
https://gist.github.com/SIGEER2222/c9452462a415ce042e323e973558e286

Do I need to configure something, or is it not possible to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/SIGEER2222/BlazorWinForms5
this my demo

Comment: Okay, now I understand that Blazor Hybrid cannot be used in a regular WinForm, the SDK must be modified.